# Naming txt file

Tags: c#

i have to create a txt file by naming it with my computer name. Example, my computer name is **PC-F0254**, but for the txt file, i only need to name it as **F0254_Rg.txt** . How can i do that?

My code :

```
string strComputerName = Environment.MachineName.ToString();
string Path = $@"..\Range\{strComputerName}_Rg.txt";

        using (StreamWriter tw = File.CreateText(Path))
        {
            while (dataRead.Read())
            {
                tw.WriteLine("Start={0}", dataRead["StrtData"]);
                tw.WriteLine("End={0}", dataRead["EndData"]);
            }
        }
        dataRead.Close();
```

Comment: I guess you could just do `strComputerName.Substring(3)` if you just need to skip the first 3 characters of the name.

Comment: Use 'Environment.MachineName.Substring(3)'; See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0

Comment: Do _all_ of the computer names have a 3-character prefix that you want to exclude? If not, you'd need to check whether it's there and remove it accordingly.

Comment: yes. all the computer names have a 3 character prefix that i need to exclude